# roscore not working, ImportError: No module named RosStreamHandler

Tags: ros-fuerte, roscore, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS-Fuerte on Linux 12.04 and I am getting an error when I try to run roscore.

```
j@instadmin-HP-Z210-Workstation:/opt/ros/fuerte$ roscore
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://instadmin-HP-Z210-Workstation:56432/
ros_comm version 1.8.11

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute     '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7    /threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [24098]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rosmaster", line 35, in <module>
    rosmaster.rosmaster_main()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/main.py", line 73, in rosmaster_main
    configure_logging()   
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/main.py", line 57, in configure_logging
    _log_filename = rosgraph.roslogging.configure_logging('rosmaster', logging.DEBUG, filename=filename)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 105, in configure_logging
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 78, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 153, in _install_handlers
    klass = _resolve(klass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 94, in _resolve
    __import__(used)
ImportError: No module named RosStreamHandler
[master] process has died [pid 24098, exit code 1, cmd rosmaster --core -p 11311 __log:=/home/jordan/.ros/log/eb156b0e-d7a6-11e2-b471-082e5f0d17cd/master.log].
log file: /home/jordan/.ros/log/eb156b0e-d7a6-11e2-b471-082e5f0d17cd/master*.log
ERROR: could not contact master [http://instadmin-HP-Z210-Workstation:11311/]
[master] killing on exit
```

When I run roswtf I get:

```
- No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65345/roscore-not-working,-importerror:-no-module-named-rosstreamhandler/) by [jjameson18](https://answers.ros.org/users/5004/jjameson18/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered a similar problem once. Check the path via echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. You have to change the path via export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=  .... . Your path might have wrong directories or the path might consist of a symbolic link which is too complex for it to handle.

---

Originally posted by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) with karma: 729 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0